# jquery is not working when we got error somewhere in page

Tags: jquery, html

i have 3 pages ,

one page is main page , and other 2 pages, (popup pages),

in main page( page No 1) , i am writing jquery references

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>
```

now i am loading second page(page No 2) in popup using **lightbox jquery popup**, i am not write any jquery reference in second page, same like when i am opening 3rd page,

now problem is , if i wrote jquery ajax function to page no 3, and if i got error there, page 2 Jquery also stop working ( for example : in page -2 , document ready  if i hide some element, it's stop to work)

why?

Comment: Are all 3 pages in the same directory?  Make sure the path in src is getting to all 3.

Comment: You should provide syntax from the second or third page.

Comment: You sure all your javascripts works correctly and the code gets executed? Becouse if there is a error in the code javascript stops executing. Try adding some alert's to check if the code is executed.

Answer (score 2):

if it is a completely new window, ie: not part of the DOM of the window that opened it, it will not have the necessary script files to run.

In your HTML for your 'child' windows, include the references to the jquery assets necessary

Comment: Forgive me if that isn't the answer you are looking for, but I had a bit of trouble following your question

Comment: ok let me tell you, there is one div on main page, and in this div , i am loading page 2, and page 3, and this div using my lightbox as popup

Comment: Are you loading your lightbox as an IFRAME? If so, that will be a major part of your problem.